# Splitting strings in PowerShell

Tags: string, powershell, split, powershell-4.0

I got a variable that contains different strings like `domainname/users/username` and `domainname/accounts/serviceUsers/serviceusername`.

Now I want to split these strings on the last "/" so I get only the last bit (username, serviceusername).

I know how to use split when specifiying exactly on which occurance of the "/" the string should be splitted, but not generally at the last "/".

```
$x = 'domainname/Accounts/ServiceUsers/serviceusername' 
$x.split('/')[3]
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hope this helps

```
$x.split('/')[-1]
```

Comment: To expand on this, PowerShell allows negative subscripting to select an array element starting from the end (last element of the array). Because 0 can't be distinguished as to positive or negative (except on certain old computers), "reverse" subscripting is 1-based instead of 0-based, and the last element of `$x` is `$x[-1]`, the next-to-last is `$x[-2]`, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Another way.  Note that -split uses regex.

```
'domainname/Accounts/ServiceUsers/serviceusername'-split '/' | 
  select -Last 1
```